# OpenGL ES 2.0 possible without NDK?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am learning Android development, specifically to eventually do OpengL 2.0 ES on it.

So far I have read that the NDK supports Opengl 2.0 ES.

However, is there also a Java API for it?

If there is a Java API for it, which one is recommended?  I know both C++ and Java, so it is not a big deal if I have to use the NDK, but I would prefer to work only in Java if possible and without a big performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use OpenGL ES 2.0 from Java without touching NDK at all.
Here is official documentation about starting OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html

Also take a look at official samples that comes together with SDK. Here are relevant the files under samples directory:

```
* ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics\GLES20Activity.java
* ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics\GLES20TriangleRenderer.java
* BasicGLSurfaceView\src\com\example\android\basicglsurfaceview\*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i searched this website has some good useful samples related to openGL

http://www.droidnova.com/?s=openGL